# How to define implicit Play ReactiveMongo handler for type parameter?

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I'm new to scala and using play2.5 + play2-reactivemongo 0.12.3.
now trying to create a base DAO trait as below.

```
trait BaseDAO[T] {
  val collectionName: String
  def reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi
  lazy val collection = reactiveMongoApi.database.map(_.collection(collectionName))

  def findOne(query: JsObject = Json.obj())(implicit reader: Reads[T]): 
    Future[Option[T]] = {
    collection.flatMap(_.find(query).one[T])
  }
}
```

And I get an error message as following.

```
could not find implicit value for parameter reader: reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentReader[T]
collection.flatMap(_.find(query).one[T])
                                    ^
```

In case of type parameter, is there any way to solve the error?

Comment: do you have a `Reads` for your `T`

Comment: No I don't. I tried "implicit val baseFormat: BSONHandler[BSONDocument, T] = Macros.handler[T]" instead. Do I need reads() and writes() for T(BSONDoocument)?

Comment: You are using a `BSONCollection` with JSON values.

Comment: You need to define the Reads for the concrete type of T

Comment: I guess that I needed collection to be "lazy val collection: Future[JSONCollection] = reactiveMongoApi.database.map(_.collection(collectionName))"

Comment: As indicated in the documentation about database resolution, never assign a DB related ressource (there collection) to a `val` (even a lazy one), or you will lose any chance to recover in case of temporary issue at DB resolution (e.g. network issue)

Comment: Thank you for your information!!